# Function Approximation: How is tile coding different from highly discretized state space?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I'm transitioning from discretization of a continuous state space to function approximation. My action and state space(3D) are both continuous. My problem suffers majorly from errors due to aliasing and nearly no convergene after training for a long time. Also I just cannot figure out how to choose the right step size for discretization.

Reading Sutton & Barto helped me understand the power of tile coding i.e having the state space described by multiple offested tilings overlapping each other. Given a continuous query/state, it is discribed by N basis functions, each corresponding to a single block/square of the criss-cross tilings it belongs to.

1) How is the performance different from going for a highly discretized state space?

2) Can anyone please point me to a working example of tile coding in python? I am learning too many things at the same time and getting super confused! (Q learning, discretization dilemma, tile coding, function approximation and handling the problem itself)

There doesn't seem to be any exhaustive Python coding tutorials for continuous problems in RL.

Comment: Regarding point 1: tiles can overlap. You can define a tile covering space [0,4] and another one covering [2,6]. They share the area between [2,4]. If you discretize the space, it's like having non-overlapping tiles.

Comment: Thanks Simon! This helps. I forgot what happens after the coding - the tile codes are being used later for approximation i.e while adjusting the summed weights towards a target value. I have another query though that I mentioned below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the Simon's comment describes, a key difference between a highly discretized state space and a function approximator using tile coding, it's the hability of tile coding to generalize the values learned from one state to other similar states (i.e., tiles can overlap). In the case of a highly discretized state space, you need to visit all (and they can be a lot) the states to obtain a good representation of the value function (or Q function).

Regarding the second question, in this [link](http://incompleteideas.net/rlai.cs.ualberta.ca/RLAI/RLtoolkit/tiles.html#Python_Versions_) you can find an implementation of tile coding (in C, C++, Lisp and Python) written by Rich Sutton and other members of his laboratory.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. There is something I don't understand in the tiles() routine - I scale my inputs [x,y] and pass them as arguments to tiles() and it returns me the indices across different tilings, I can sum the corresponding weights for these indices and approx my value function. This assumes state space as a unit square x,y. Say I call tiles() with two inputs, (x=1.3,y=2.0) and (x=2.4,y=2.0). x,y are scaled first and then tile coded. Won't returnd tiles correspond to different for both these queries? Unlike discretization, where there is a fixed grid of the state space irrespective of query x,y

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding your question. But, in tile coding, we can say that there are several fixed grids of discretizations (maybe fig. 4 of this paper can help you: http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~laurissa/Laurissas_Pages/Publications_files/IASTED_LNT.pdf). So the calls to tiles() with those inputs can return the same value depending on the granularity of the tiles. In any case, I don't know the details of the implementation :(

Comment: Great! That's how I understand it as well. So Fig.4  of this paper, I am saying the size of these tilings (each patched grid) will change as I change the inputs I pass onto the tiles() routine, so the returned tile indices will be different and likewise the weights that I sum (basically the approximation of the value function) will be different too right?

Comment: In your example, assuming two points in a 2D space p1=(1.3, 2) and p2=(2.4, 2), if we scale them to be in the unit square (e.g., dividing by 2.4), then  p1=(0.54, 0.83) and p2=(0.999, 0.83). Using 1 tiling, depending on the size of the tiles, the call to tiles() returns the same or different values. Assuming only two tiles (tile_size=0.5), then in the calls tiles(1, 1000, [0.54/tile_size, 0.83/tile_size]) and tiles(1, 1000, [0.99/tile_size, 0.83/tile_size]), the returned tile indexes should be equal. If we have more tiles (e.g, tile_size=0.2), they should be different. What is your doubt?

Comment: Ah okay! Now it makes sense, I have to scale externally each dimension of the data point by a certain number such that it falls within [0,1]. Then I passed these scaled values to tiles(). Like you divided by 2.4 in the above example, I should divide each state variable by the maximum value of that state variable in my dataset right? This should work in my case but since these values are being generated online, how do I know this maximum (scaling) value?

Comment: Exactly, you can find more elaborated examples in the documentation (http://incompleteideas.net/rlai.cs.ualberta.ca/RLAI/RLtoolkit/tiles.html). I don't know exactly your case, but you should fix the range of each state variable before applying tile coding. Maybe you can obtain a represantative sample of states before learning and compute the min and max values? It depends totally on your domain.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Pablo's answer -

Tile coding (as a special case of coarse coding) can be compared to simple state aggregation. A simple state aggregation is, for example, a grid. Tile coding would be a stack of grids on top of each other, each shifted a bit from the previous.

The benefits are two fold - it allows you to have **better discrimination** (more fine grained control, less bias) **without loss of generalization** (less variance).

This is because with tile coding **you cover more states, with less features**.

A grid is similar to one-hot-encoding. A 3x3 grid is equivalent to a 9-Dimension 1-hot-encoding vector - and covers 10 states in total - either an object is in one of the 9 grid blocks, or is in none of them.

[image]

So the middle point could be represented by (0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0).

How about you take 4 - 1x1 boxes, and just shift them a little bit 0.5 box (so that they cover 2x2 area of the grid each).

[image]

Now you cover 10 states with only 4 dimensions, or 4 inputs: red box, green box, blue box, and purple box.

Now the same middle point could be represented by (1,1,1,1).

This means you can generalize better. Before - gradient descent would only affect that middle point parameters. Now, since a point is influenced by a combination of few features - all of these features parameters will be affected. Which also allows for faster learning (as Pablo mentions).

Coursera offers (a paid) [specialization](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/reinforcement-learning?) which has exercises you need to implement in Python. Specifically Course 3 week 3 let's you work with tiles. They are using an **updated** (compared to Pablo's answer) [Sutton's implementation of the code](http://incompleteideas.net/tiles/tiles3.html), which is more simplified and uses python 3. Since the code can be quite cryptic at first, here is [my comments on it](https://github.com/MaverickMeerkat/Reinforcement-Learning/blob/master/Tile%20Coding.ipynb).

Comment: hey nice explanation, but I don't really understand how is it 4 dimensions in your statement 'Now you cover 10 states with only 4 dimensions'. According to Sutton & Barton book, it is 64 (4 boxes of dimension 2*2) components. In the former case (state aggregation), we covered 10 states in 9 components. IDK if the component is the same as the dimension in your answer.

Comment: @Riya208 we now have 4 dimensions corresponding to the 4 different boxes - and together they cover all 9 boxes. E.g. (1,0,0,0) corresponds to the 4-top-left red box, (1,1,0,0) corresponds to the 2-top-middle intersection between the red and the green box, etc.

Comment: @Riya208 if you could reference the exact place in the book I can have a look.

Comment: The exact place in the book is Chapter 9: 'On-policy Prediction with Approximation', section 9.5.4 Tile Coding. The statement is 'These four tiles correspond to four features that become active when the state occurs. Specifically, the feature vector x(s) has one component for each tile in each tiling. In this example, there are 4*4*4 = 64 components, all of which will be 0 except for the four corresponding to the tiles that s falls within.' (in the paragraph below Figure 9.9) I have the second edition of the textbook.

Comment: @Riya208 they are using a different example. You can see by the picture what they meant. I have 4 1x1 boxes, who are 0.5 box apart. They are using 4 4x4 boxes who are 0.25 boxes apart - which covers 13x13 grid completely. They reduced the dimension from 169 1-hot to 64.

Comment: Oh okay. Now I got it. My bad. I thought even you were using 4 4x4 boxes and hence the confusion. Sorry and Thank you :)

Comment: @Riya208 the boxes are technically 1x1, but because they are 0.5 box apart, each covers 2x2 area - I also edited the answer to make this more clear. They are using boxes that are technically 4x4, but since each is 0.25 box apart, they actually cover 16x16 area, though only 13x13 of it is completely covered.